# How to update or replace the element in LinkedHashSet using specific index?

Tags: collections, set, linkedhashset

I am trying to update the value from LinkedHashSet from specific element but there is no set method in this class like arraylist has set method so match the index with my index and then remove it and again add it but it is adding at last in the linked hash set....so please help me to solve this..

To set the element in LinkedHashSet

Comment: That’s not how a `Set` works. If you want `List` behavior, use a `List`.